# PowerShell iTunes RSS Podcast Creation

Tags: xml, powershell, rss

I need to programatically create a valid iTunes podcast RSS XML with PowerShell.

I'm having problems creating the namespaces for all of the iTunes specific elements, such as...

```xml
<itunes:image>
<itunes:name>
```

I've tried importing the below using Get-Content, but with no luck.

```xml
<itunes xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">
<image>"logo.png"</image>
</itunes>
```

```bsh
[xml]$itunesxml = Get-Content -Path './itunes.xml'
```

```xml
<root>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">
    <image>"logo.png"</image>
</root>
```

Importing this gives me...

```bsh
Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The 'xsl:stylesheet' start tag on line 3 position 2 does not match the end tag of 'root'. Line 7, position 3."
At line:1 char:1
+ [xml]$itunesxml = Get-Content -Path './itunes.xml'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

I expect to be able to generate some XML that I can add to the XML that I am already able to generate programatically.

Answer (score 0):

The closing element of *xsl:stylesheet* is missing, try :

```
<root>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">
    <image>"logo.png"</image>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</root>
```